# Copying selection from last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table, with headers in the range `A2:V2` and the data in the range `A3:VXX`, where `XX` is the last row number.

I am trying to write a macro which duplicates the values of the last row, but only for columns `A:P`. So Duplicating the values in `AXX:PXX`. I have no issues finding and copying the *entire* last row, however I cannot copy a limited range within it.

Apologies earlier for not including the code I have used.

```
With Activesheet 
    .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).entirerow.copy 
End With
```

Comment: Please show your code. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: "I have no issues copying the entire last row" - show us how you do this and we can show you how to copy the range you want.

Comment: Apologies about earlier yes. I have now included code for copying entire row. When I enter a range however it does not work. I suspect i need to define the lastrow?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the entire row set the range:

```
Dim lastRow as long

With Activesheet 
    lastRow = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).Row
    .Range(.Cells(lastrow,"A"),.Cells(lastrow,"P")).copy 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Columns("A:P").Copy
End With
```

or, since `ActiveSheet` is the default sheet, simply:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Columns("A:P").Copy
```